# Emacs Org Mode: how to reduce line spacing?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, line-spacing

For some reason, a few months ago the line spacing in Org Mode has increased. It's the line spacing between display lines, not merely between paragraphs or headings.

The variable "line-spacing" is nil. Actually setting it doesn't help.

If I open a non-org-mode text file in emacs, the line spacing is fine.

Does anyone know what I can do? I've looked through the org-appearance customization menu and cannot find an obvious variable to change that would affect this.

Does anyone know what variable(s) would affect org-mode faces and line width but not affect other types of files? (elisp, text, *.md, etc)

UPDATE: I discovered that the issue comes from org-indent-mode. I like the other aspects of org-indent-mode, so I'm trying to find the setting within org-indent-mode that causes my text to be spaced out.

Comment: What's your Org and Emacs version. Can you reproduce with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Emacs 28.1
org-mode = 9.5.2

Comment: Also, I determined that the problem is with org-indent-mode